# two-way binding in flex 4

Tags: data-binding, flex4

suppose i have a variable :

```
 [Bindable] public var clickedText:String
```

and when i click on an item on a list component, this clickedText stores the value this way :

```
clickedText = listID.selectedItem;
```

and then bind this variable to another child component this way:

```
<component: childComp id = newid transferredText ="{clickedText}"/>
```

now, it works fine in the childComp such that the value is transferred to the child component but when i modify the transferredText, i want it to also inform the clickedText variable of the parent component that the value has changed and update the clickedText. so, in summary i need a two-way binding..i tried the @{clickedText} thing but not working..
so, the clickedText updates the transferredText and the transferredText updates the clickedText as well.

Anyone knows how to help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [BindingUtils](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/binding/utils/BindingUtils.html).[bindProperty](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/binding/utils/BindingUtils.html#bindProperty%28%29) function.

Comment: that doesn't really solve my problem. need a way such that when you set clickedText = listID.selectedItem; then mayb the clickedText = "hello"; now, i bind that to the transferredText = "{clickedText}; and in the child component, the transferredText = "hello"; now, what if i change the transferredText = "world", i want the clickedText in the parent component to change to world immediately as well..

Comment: There are two things that you can use in Flex to create bindings between objects. BindingUtils and ChangeWatcher. I think what you need is a ChangeWatcher. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/binding/utils/ChangeWatcher.html I have successfully created two-way bindings using both BindingUtils and ChangeWatchers. However unlike BindingUtils, you should manually handle the event dispatched.

Comment: hi @Ranhiru Cooray, i read on an article that it only updates a variable..which is what i want but in this case, there are two variables..one belongs to the parent component and the other belongs to the second variable. so, if the variable_1 in the parent component changes, the variable_2 in the child component gets updated with what the content of variable_1 is and if variable_2 changes as well, variable_1 is updated with the value of variable_2..so, do you think the ChangeWatcher is suitable for this?